# Why I can't populate the data from organization?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have 2 schemas.

`organization Schema` and `inventory schema`

Organization Schema was like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const organizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  organizationName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

organizationSchema.virtual("inventories", {
  ref: "Inventory",
  // Localfield is user id
  localField: "_id",
  // forefield is owner field in task
  foreignField: "owner",
});


organizationSchema.virtual("user", {
  ref: "User",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "organizationId",
});

const Organization = mongoose.model("Organization", organizationSchema);
```

Inventory Schema was like this

```
const inventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  inventoryName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Organization'
  },
  users: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
});

inventorySchema.virtual("items", {
  ref: "Item",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "inventoryId",
});

const Inventory = mongoose.model("Inventory", inventorySchema);
```

So in the api path. I wanna grab all the inventory related to certain organization.
So i am populating like this. But I only get back the organization without populated data.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
router.get("/organizations/:orgId/inventory", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let organization = await Organization.findOne({
      _id: req.params.orgId,
    }).populate('user')
    res.send(organization)
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(404).send({ error: "Organization not found" });
  }
});
```

API I am calling `{{url}}/organizations/65ec63bee52ddf849fe70f76/inventory`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your code is trying to populate `user` and not `inventories` so you need to change your code to:

```js
const organization = await Organization.findOne({
   _id: req.params.orgId,
}).populate('inventories');
```

Secondly, when you use the express [`res.send()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) method the argument passed to this method can be one of many different types such an `String`, `Array`, `Object` etc. Express will use the argument type to determine which `Content-Type` to set in the response header. In your case you are sending an object so express will set that to `Content-Type: application/json`.

That's important to understand because mongoose virtuals are not included when the data is passed to `toJSON()` and `toObject()`. Since `inventories` is a virtual it won't be output in the data. You can fix that by setting the option in your schema:

```js
const organizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   organizationName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
},{
   toJSON: { virtuals: true },
   toObject: { virtuals: true }
});
```